# Sortable: Move values to another group

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

[image: Example]
Refer to the above image. I can sort/interchange Kerwin and Bonn in GROUP1. I can also interchange GROUPS. Now my problem is how can I sort/move Kerwin to other group. Example: move kerwin to group 2

Here's Demo + Code

```js
$( ".content" ).sortable();
$( ".content" ).disableSelection();
$( ".subcontent" ).sortable();
$( ".subcontent" ).disableSelection();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table id="subsortsortable">
        <tbody class="content">
            <tr><td>
                <table>
                    <thead>GROUP 1</thead>
                    <tbody class="subcontent">
                        <tr><td>Kerwin</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Bonn</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
                <table>
                    <thead>GROUP 2</thead>
                    <tbody class="subcontent">
                        <tr><td>Ivan</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Bobby</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
                <table>
                    <thead>GROUP 3</thead>
                    <tbody class="subcontent">
                        <tr><td>Wil</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Michael</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td></tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sortable({connectWith:['.subcontent']})`,

```js
$( ".content" ).sortable({
    dropOnEmpty: true
});
$( ".content" ).disableSelection();
$( ".subcontent" ).sortable({
    connectWith:['.subcontent', '>*:not(.sort-disabled)'],
    items:"tr[class!=sort-disabled]"
});
$( ".subcontent" ).disableSelection();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table id="subsortsortable">
    <tbody class="content">
        <tr><td>
            <table>
                <thead>GROUP 1</thead>
                <tbody class="subcontent">
                    <tr><td>Kerwin</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Bonn</td></tr>
                    <tr class="sort-disabled"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <table>
                <thead>GROUP 2</thead>
                <tbody class="subcontent">
                    <tr><td>Ivan</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Bobby</td></tr>
                    <tr class="sort-disabled"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <table>
                <thead>GROUP 3</thead>
                <tbody class="subcontent">
                    <tr><td>Wil</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Michael</td></tr>
                    <tr class="sort-disabled"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have another problem. If the GROUP doesn't have values, I cant add value/names via dragging.